# How to I get a test class working for a standardsetcontroller that bases off one record

Tags: apex, unit-test, standardsetcontroller

I have a difficult issue because I have essentially a standardcontroller that runs off the current opportunity but it needs to be used via a relatedlist button on a custom object so it has to be a standardsetcontroller to be recognized by the custom object.  I have it working but when trying to create the test class I cannot get it to recognize the controller.
I just keep getting the error 
Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardSetController].(Id)

Here is the start of my extension class up to where it instantiates the controller

```
public with sharing class opportunityContactEntryExtension {

  public Opportunity theOpp {get;set;}
  public String searchString {get;set;}
  public Opportunity_Contact_Role__c[] chosencontacts {get;set;}
  public contact[] availablecontacts {get;set;}
  public Account theAccount {get;set;}   

  public String toSelect {get; set;}
  public String toUnselect {get; set;}
  public Decimal Total {get;set;}

  public Boolean overLimit {get;set;}

  private Opportunity_Contact_Role__c[] forDeletion = new Opportunity_Contact_Role__c[]{};

  public opportunityContactEntryExtension(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller) {
    Id opptyId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    // Get information about the Opportunity being worked on
    theOpp = [select Id, AccountId, Account.Name from Opportunity where Id = :opptyId limit 1];
  }
}
```

and this is the start of my test class up to where it gives the error:

```
@istest
private class testopportunitycontactEntry {

static testMethod void theTests(){
    //Create Test Data

    Account a=new Account(Name='Test Account');
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='John',LastName='Doe');
    insert c;
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opportunity',closedate=system.today(), stagename='Confirmed Teaching/Class Schedule',Probability=0.95);
    insert o;      
    Opportunity_Contact_Role__c cocr = new Opportunity_Contact_Role__c (Opportunity__c = o.id, Contact__c=c.id, role__c='Decision Maker', Primary__c=True) ;     
    insert cocr;  

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    //  test opportunityContactEntry
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    // load the page       
    PageReference pageRef = Page.opportunitycontactEntry;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',cocr.Opportunity__c);
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

    // load the extension
    opportunityContactEntryExtension oCEE = new OpportunityContactEntryExtension(new ApexPages.StandardSetController(cocr.Opportunity__c));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you create a collection of 1 to pass into your constructor? e.g.

```
List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
opps.add( [ Select Id From Opportunity Where Id = : cocr.Opportunity__c ] );
opportunityContactEntryExtension oCEE = new OpportunityContactEntryExtension(new ApexPages.StandardSetController( opps ));
```

At the moment, you're just passing in `cocr.Opportunity__c` which is an Id of the Opportunity and there is no constructor that accepts Id for the StandardSetController class.

See the docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm).

Comment: That was it.  I had tried adding a list before and it wouldn't let me...I got an error saying that List was unexpected or something like that.  I must have done something wrong though because this time it let me add it.  That was it!